# How to extract No. of Days between 2 dates in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want No. of days between these 2 dates using Oracle SQL

Dates:

```
BETWEEN "1/1/2018" AND "6/11/2018"
```

How to write SQL Query?

Comment: Do you want a count of the number of days between the start and end date? Do you want a list of all the days between those two bounds? Do you want to filter a table to only get rows with a column between those dates?

Answer (score 2):

```
between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-11-06'
```

where DATE literal looks exactly like that: `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`

In your example:

- double quote's can't be used
- even if you used single quotes, that would be a string, not DATE so you'd depend on whether Oracle is capable of converting it (implicitly) to date or not
- therefore, always use dates, not strings

**[EDIT]**

This is how you select the whole *calendar* between those two dates:

```
select date '2018-01-01' + level - 1
from dual
connect by level <= date '2018-11-06' - date '2018-01-01' + 1;
```

Comment: Ok how to extract days from these dates

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I thought that there's a table which contains some dates. OK then, you need to create a *calendar* - I edited my message, have a look.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out you can simply divide two dates, but there is also no need for any additional arithmetic.

The code:

```
select to_date('6/11/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date('1/1/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  from dual;
```

> The result:  309

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
select date'2018-11-06' - date'2018-01-01' + 1 as days_difference
  from dual;

DAYS_DIFFERENCE
---------------
     310
```

or

```
with t( myDate ) as
(
 select date'2018-11-06' from dual union all 
 select date'2018-01-01' from dual
)
select max(myDate) - min(myDate) + 1 as days_difference
  from t;

DAYS_DIFFERENCE
---------------
     310
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simple do:

```
select date1-date2 form dual;
```

or

```
select (sysdate-to_date('01-jan-2018'))-(sysdate-to_date('10-jan-2018'))from dual;
```